# How can I get Phusion Passenger to use the correct version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

My colleague has a Rails development environment using Nginx, Phusion Passenger, and RVM. When he tries to load a project, the it complains that it requires a different version of Ruby than what is available:

```
The given ruby environment requires ruby-1.9.2-p290 (versus ree-1.8.7-2011.03) (RVM::IncompatibleRubyError)
```

We are switching from REE to MRI Ruby. Here's what I've checked so far:

- `.rvmrc` in that directory is `rvm use --create default@ourapp`.
- `rvm list default` returns `ruby-1.9.2-p290`
- We've changed out and back into the directory and seen that it says it's using 1.9.2
- The configuration file for nginx sets `passenger_root` and `passenger_ruby` correctly, as far as I can tell
- Passenger has been compiled with Ruby 1.9.2.

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: The issue ended up being so specific to his setup that I doubt this will be useful to anyone else. Since I can no longer delete this, I voted to close it as "too localized".

Comment: Yeah, but comment pointing do documentation still valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the documentation?

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation_and_support#documentation

You use a wrapper by specifying --passenger for your rvm command and tell Apache or Nginx to use the wrapper it generates. Ruby isn't 'compiled in'.

This will only give you one rvm instance but it will work.

For multiple RVM's the only solution I've ever found to work is to use Unicorn and reverse proxy to the running unicorn processes. Unicorn scales properly and is a grown up unix citizen - it's what I use for production, personally.

EDIT - have just noticed that Passenger 3 is a bit more RVM-friendly (as given in the documentation above) - but you still have to run against a wrapper.

On a Mac, for dev, 37 Signals have an alternative called POW that allows easy config for dev environments.

Comment: Link updated to point to new site

Answer (score 0):

Passenger has to be compiled with a specific version of Ruby and is locked in to that from that point forward. You can't just switch it around in RVM without also running through the `passenger-install-X-module` regimen.

Comment: Good catch, but I was wrong - Passenger had been compiled with Ruby 1.9.2. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use different rubies and have RVM respected, use apache + unicorn. Install the mod_proxy and mod_rewrite modules for apache, set up unicorn_rails with a unicorn.conf and run 'unicorn_rails -E production -D -c config/unicorn.conf'. This is assuming you put the config for unicorn in the rails app's config directory.